# DialogPreference textview is dark on android 2.3.5, works on >4.0

Tags: android, preference

I have a strange problem. I want to display license information viewable from the settings in the app. I am using a very simple custom `DialogPreference` which just hosts a `scrollveiw` with a `textview` inside. Everything works fine except that on my test device running android 2.3.5 the dialog is very dark and hard to read. It works perfectly on my main device running android >4.0. What might be the problem?

What it looks like on android 2.3.5:
[image]

My XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_margin="7dip" />

</ScrollView>
```

My code:

```
public class PreferenceDialogOpenSourceLicenses extends DialogPreference {
    private String dialogeMessage;
    private Context context;

    public PreferenceDialogOpenSourceLicenses(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        setPersistent(false);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_dialog_license);
        dialogeMessage = getActionBarSherlockLicense();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindDialogView(View view){
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.info_textview);
        textView.setText(dialogeMessage);
        super.onBindDialogView(view);
    }

    private String getActionBarSherlockLicense() {
         try {
                InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("licence_apache_v2.txt");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                String text = new String(buffer);

                return text;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return context.getString(R.string.error_could_not_get_license);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not difficult to create a custom dialog using `Dialog` or `DialogFragment`, so it will be better to create a custom view look liked a dialog and set it to `Dialog`. The benefit of doing this is that you have control over the view instead of fixing various styles.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your styles.xml in your value folder! Put anything else in the parent of your app theme... That should fix the "dark" theme issue ;) ex: .Light theme

After that, you can change the styles.xml of the value-v11 folder & value-v14 folder to holo, which will take Holo theme in consideration when the API level support it!